# Inequalites withen Contours

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$Proposition:$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Initially the function:$f(z)=\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^{2}}$ was considered due to the fact we have a trigonometric term within our numerator.Our function $f(z)$ was integrated  on the upper semicircle within our Contour,our Semicircular contour we are integrating over can be seen within $Figure\, (1)$.
$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, $[image: Figure 1]

$$Figure \, (1).$$
After, applying Cauchy's Theorem the initial observation was made:
$$\int_{-R}^{\epsilon}\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx+\int_{\gamma \epsilon^{+}}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}dz+\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx+\int_{\gamma R^{+}}\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}dz=0$$

The author let $R \rightarrow \infty$, and observed that the following inequality occurs:
$$\left|\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^{2}}\right| \le \frac{2}{|z|^{2}}$$

Initially, in summary the beginnings of my misunderstandings lie with author notion of the inequaility after letting $R \rightarrow \infty$, how would one justify the following inequality ?

Comment: The inequality is just some simple algebra and triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ has a non-negative imaginary part, say $z=a+ib$ with $b\geq 0$, then $e^{iz}=e^{ia}\cdot e^{-b}$ has modulus $e^{-b}\leq 1$, hence $1-e^{iz}$ has modulus $\leq 1+1 = 2$.

Comment: In general when $R \rightarrow \infty$, is there another techniques to derive the inequality ?

Comment: This is a technique that works for any radius large enough, but you need to exploit the fact that z is in the upper half plane, otherwise the contribute given by the exponential term might grow unbounded. It is just a minor twist on the usual triangle inequality.